# How do I call a file.js into a file.html

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is run the script in file.js to onload prompt username. But for some reason every time the script is on the html file it works but when I move it to the file.js it doesn't work. Any Idea why this is happening?

My main goal is to separate my scripts from my html.

**file.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "file.js"></script>
<body onload = "myFunction()">
</html>
```

**file.js**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Your Name here");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you need `<script>` tags if it is a .js file?

Answer (score 0):

`file.js` is a JavaScript file - it can't have `<script></script>` tags in it since those are [HTML script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tags. Remove those and it works.

Keep in mind:

- Your `<head>` tag wasn't closed.
- Your `<body>` tag wasn't closed.
- Your function isn't closed properly, you're missing a `}`.
- You were missing an element with the ID `"Name"`.
- JS files are best put at the end of your `<body>` so the browser can render the page without having to wait for the JS files to load. The code will still work because the `onload` event is fired [at the end of the document loading process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

Working code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Your Name here");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="myFunction()">
    <div id="Name"></div>

    <script src="file.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```